# ifstream >> reading same line over again

Tags: c++

I'm trying to read in formatted hex data into unsigned ints using the >> operator. The code I'm using is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  ifstream in(argv[1]);
  unsigned int addr;
  unsigned int op;
  unsigned int data;
  do
  {
    in >> hex >> addr >> hex >> op >> hex >> data;
    cout << addr << " " << op << " " << data << '\n';
    if (in.eof()) break;
  } while(1);
  return 0;
}
```

This works on a 300 line file just fine, but when I try it on a different file, it reads the 5th line repeatedly then seg faults, and I cannot figure out why. The first five lines are

```
FD2C FF EB
4FE9 FF 32
276E FF 6E
5C09 FF A3
7739 FF 36
```

The offending line is

```
7739 FF 36
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

## Edit:

I modified my code so it looks like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  ifstream in(argv[1]);
  unsigned int addr;
  unsigned int op;
  unsigned int data;
  while (in >> hex >> addr >> hex >> op >> hex >> data)
  {
    cout << addr << " " << op << " " << data << '\n';
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This solves the problem of reading the 5th line over and over again but it still segfaults, albeit on another line. I'm going to look further and see if I can pin it down.

Answer (score -2):

FF is new page symbol and then it is followed by a dollar sign $ which is 36, maybe it thinks that 36 is a pointer to something. try to change unsigned int to unsigned char.

EDIT: this reads everything in without problems and output is in hex values good luck.

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <fstream>

 int main(int argc, char** argv)
 {
 std::ifstream in; in.open("tst.tst",std::ios::in);
 unsigned char addr;
 unsigned char op;
 unsigned char data;
 while (in >>std::hex>> addr>>std::hex>> op>>std::hex>> data)
 {
  std::cout << (int)addr <<std::hex << " " << (int)op<<std::hex << " " << (int)data<<std::hex<< "\n";
  }
  return 0;
 }
```